# Restoring active tab when navigating back in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that consists of multiple logical views (with matching routes). Each view displays multiple tabs. Based on the active tab, I determine which parts of the UI to show / hide.

Since the tabs are not part of the route, loading the view always shows the first tab. This is fine for the most part, however when the user navigates to another view and then navigates back (using the browser back button), it makes sense to restore the previously selected tab.

Any ideas how to achieve that without adding the active tab index to the route?

BTW the reasons I'd like to avoid adding the active tab to the route are:

1. I don't want the tab selection history to be added to the browsing history (clicking back shouldn't take you to the previous tab on the same view, but rather to the previous view)
2. I don't want the controller to reload

So far I thought about using local storage to store the last active tab in the view, and restoring it when detecting that the browser navigated back. But this feels like a hack, so I'm trying to avoid it. I'm looking for a solution that feels "right" by angular's way of doing things...

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `ui.router` or the standard angular router?

Comment: I'm using the standard router.

Comment: @M.S, did you achieve this? I also came across the same scenario. Need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most lightweight "angular"-way would probably be to create a service which stores last selected tab per view. This would not survive page reload.

In order to survive page reload, the service could store the data within `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

However, this still won't work when copy-pasting the URL. Storing selected tab within URL would solve this.

Your concerns about storing selected tab within URL are unfounded. Selected tab can be updated within URL without compromising browser history nor reloading the component, e.g.:

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { tab: event.index }, replaceUrl: true });
}
```

It would be even better to label your tabs via "ariaLabbeledby" and then use `event.tab.ariaLabbeledby` to avoid problems if tabs are re-arranged.